# How to run Jenkins job on multiple agents in parallel using declarative pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a supposedly simple task: I want to run a job on multiple agents in parallel.
Even though I'm a bit of a noob with Jenkins, I've googled a bit, and got to the conclusion that the  preferred solution is to use Matrix directive.

I've read  [Matrix official docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix) and [this blog](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/) and still can't solve it completely.
But I'm close, so I assume I just need a bit of help.
The agents I need job to run on - have label: 'vms'.

The below pipeline will run job on **some** of required agents that have 'vms' label - equivalent to the amount of values for **DUMMY_AXIS** axis.
For example, 'vms' label has 3 agents, pipeline below will run stages on 2 out of 3.
How to fix the issue, so that stages would run once on each agent from given label , regardless of how many agents there are?

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Update TestHostAgent') {
            matrix {
              agent {
                label 'vms'
              }
               axes {
                  axis {
                            name 'DUMMY_AXIS'
                            values 'dummy_val_1', 'dummy_val_2'
                  }
               }
                stages {
                    stage('Build') {
                        steps {
                            echo "Build stage"
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Test') {
                        steps {
                            script {
                                echo "Test Step"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```